# how to speed up spatial index creation with many tables?

Tags: oracle-spatial

I have created more than 500 tables with geometry columns ,

it's taking more time for spatial index creation after inserting data, how can I create spatial  index for all tables within a few seconds,

are there any other way to speed up for spatial index creation?

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you want to speed up ? The creation of the spatial indexes (= the CREATE INDEX commands) ? Or the inserts/updates to the tables. How big are those tables ? And how long is acceptable for your business process ?

Indexes are typically created once only upon the initial creation and population of a spatial table. Unless your application is one that inserts massive quantities of data at short intervals, or one that tracks moving objects, there is no need whatsoever to rebuild the indexes after the initial creation. They are obviously maintained automatically.

As for the time to build a spatial index, it does obviously take longer (sometimes significantly so) than building an index on the same number of names. Obviously, the larger your tables, the longer that can take. Then again, if you think you can build 500 indexes (spatial or not) in a few seconds, you are deluded, even if you use very powerful hardware and the tables are empty.

There are two ways to make your index builds take less time:

1) For large tables, partition them and do the build in parallel. That is only possible if you own the partitioning option (only available in EE). Then again, that makes sense only for large tables - i.e. 50 mio rows and more. It makes little sense on small tables.

2) For a large number of smallish tables, just do the builds in parallel, i.e. run multiple index creations concurrently. Use the database's scheduler (DBMS_SCHEDULER) to orchestrate that.

If what you are after is how to accelerate data ingestion (moving objects, tracking, ...) then you need to explain a bit more about your workflow.